# Make promoted links responsive

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, promoted-links, responsive

I have managed to add some JavaScript that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644742/sharepoint-2013-how-to-make-promoted-links-responsive) and almost get my promoted links to be responsive.

The only issue is that when my screen gets below a resolution of approximately 900px the promoted links end up on a single line each.

I have seen the answer to the question asked within Stack Overflow but do not understand where it is I need to add the "!important" tag in order to override the SharePoint CSS which appears to be causing this.

Could anyone please advise on how to fix this.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ7').removeClass('ms-promlink-body');
$('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ7').addClass('row container-fluid');
$('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ7').children().removeClass('ms-tileview-tile-root');
$('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ7').children().addClass('col-md-4 tilesresponsive');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this link to download the js:

http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/08/11/display-promoted-links-multiple-lines/

Or if unavailable the page has been archived at the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151016080030/http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/08/11/display-promoted-links-multiple-lines/) along with the code if you search for "Download JavaScript" on that page.

I didn't need to change anything in the code. Just save it, publish it and add the js-link in your webpart properties.

My location is: ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/MultilinePromotedLinks.js